# Signal handlers in mini shell project

Tags: c, signals, exec, fork, handler

This is what happens in my signal handler. Also signal_flag is a global variable.

```
volatile sig_atomic_t signal_flag = 0;
void sig_handler(int signo) {
    if (signo == SIGTSTP) {
        signal_flag = 1;
    }
}
```

This the condition that occurs, provided my fork() works as its supposed to. I have the sleep set to 5 so I have enough time to press CTRL+Z after a command I'll give as an input and suspend the process.

```
        pid_t child_pid = fork();
        int status;
        //GOT A SIGNAL.
        if (signal(SIGTSTP, sig_handler) != SIG_ERR) {
            signal(SIGTSTP, SIG_IGN);
            kill(child_pid, SIG_IGN);
            insert_suspended_process(child_pid, ACTIVE);
            //_exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
        if (child_pid < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "execute: fork failed.\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if (child_pid == 0) {
            /* child process. */
            //print_child_messages();
            char bin[512];
            strcpy(bin, command[0]);
            //strcat(bin, command[0]);

            if (bars > 0) {
                //Houston, we have pipes, I REPEAT, WE HAVE PIPES!
                int pipefd[2], status;
                pid_t cpid;
                if (pipe(pipefd) == -1) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "execute: pipe failed.\n");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                cpid = fork();

                pipe(pipefd);

            }
            sleep(3);


            //executing...
            execvp(bin, command);
            _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);        //safer than exit().
        }
        else {
            /* parent process. */
            //print_parent_messages(child_pid);
            //signal(SIGTSTP, SIG_IGN);


            waitpid(child_pid, NULL, 0);

        }
```

I'm making a shell as part of homework, and I'm requested to handle the SIGTSTP signal in a way that, when the user presses CTRL+Z my shell will suspend the ongoing process(i have set sleep(3) so I can suspend even a simple `ls -al` process) 
My problem is that my code adds the process with that pid to my list via the `insert_suspended_process(pid_t)` function but this occurs without me pressing the CTRL+Z signal. Any thoughts or quidelines?

Comment: You should have declared `volatile sig_atomic_t signal_flag = 0;`; also compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`), **use the debugger** (`gdb`) and also `strace` & `valgrind`

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to check the result of the fork() in the if (i==12). Also installing the signal handler AFTER the fork is a problem waiting to happen ..

Comment: But in order to be in that part of the code, then fork() returned 0. that's why i'm in the child process. What I want to do is suspend the process with CTRL+Z without stopping my own shell.